# How to exclude one template from apply-templates?

Tags: xslt, xpath-1.0

That's my source file(that can't be changed)

```
<root>
    <status> status </status> 
        <content>
        <Description>
            <title>Title </title>
            <some_node>some node </some_node>
           </Description>
    </content>
</root>
```

Sometimes I need title to be displayed before status. That's my code:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet>
    <xsl:param name="TitleOnTop" select="'true'"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:if test="$TitleOnTop='true'">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//title[1]"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:if>
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$TitleOnTop='true'">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::title)]"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="title">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    
   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that title is displayed twice. I searched for solution of how to exclude template from aplly-template, but nothing seems to work, title is still displayed both before and after status. How do I fix that?

Output I get :

Title  status

```
        Title 
        some node
```

Output I want:
Title  status
some node

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not code snippets taken out of context. Also show the expected output.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Edited post. Is that better?